# Problem Using Two Count()'s On Same Column

Tags: t-sql, count

I'm trying to get two different counts on the same column. The two counts work fine when in separate queries, but I'm just not sure how to put them together into one query. I have two tables, which are `DailyFieldRecord` and `AB953`. `DailyFieldRecord` contains: `DailyFieldRecordID` and `ActivityCodeID`. The `AB953` table contains:`DailyFieldRecordID, ItemID, and GroupID`. `Count1` will return the count of the `DailyfieldrecordID's` that contain `ActivityCodeID=387` and `GroupID=260` and that DON'T have `ItemID in (1302,1303,1305,1306)`. `Count2` will return the count of the `DailyfieldrecordID's` that contain `ActivityCodeID=387` and `GroupID=260` and that HAVE `ItemID in (1302,1303,1305,1306)`. So they are similar, but I'm just not sure how to combine them into one query. I put an OR in the where clause between the two constraints, which I know is wrong, but I'm just not sure how to do this.

```
    DailyFieldRecord:                   AB953:
DailyFieldRecordID ActivityCodeID    DailyFieldRecordID:  ItemID: GroupID:
   657                 387                657               1305    210
   888                 420                657               1333    260
   672                 387                657               1335    260  
                                          888               1302    210
                                          888               1336    260
                                          672               1327    260
                                          672               1334    260 
                                          672               1335    260
Expected Output:
Count1:      Count2:
   3            2
Count1 is supposed to count:                Count2 is supposed to count:
   672    1327    260                  657     1333     260
   672    1334    260                  657     1335     260
   672    1335    260

SELECT COUNT(ActivityCodeID) as Count1, COUNT(ActivityCodeID) As Count2
    FROM AB953 ab
    JOIN DailyFieldRecordID dfr on 
         dfr.DailyFieldRecordID=ab.DailyFieldRecordID

     WHERE dfr.ActivityCodeID=387 and ab.GroupID=260 and NOT exists(
          select b.DailyFieldRecordID
          FROM DailyFieldRecordID b
          WHERE ab.DailyFieldRecordID = b.DailyFeildRecordID AND 
                b.ItemID in (1302,1303,1305,1306))
     OR
          dfr.ActivityCodeID=387 and ab.GroupID=260 and exists(
          select b.DailyFieldRecordID
          FROM DailyFieldRecordID b
          WHERE ab.DailyFieldRecordID = b.DailyFeildRecordID AND 
                b.ItemID in (1302,1303,1305,1306))
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the list of `DailyFieldRecordID` for `ItemID in (1302,1303,1305,1306)` (Query 1) and then incorporate query to your Final Query.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/19a31/1)

Query 1:

```
SELECT AB1.DailyFieldRecordID,SUM(CASE WHEN AB1.ItemID IN (1302,1303,1305,1306) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM AB953 AB1
GROUP BY AB1.DailyFieldRecordID
```

Final Query:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN EX=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT1,SUM(EX) AS COUNT2
FROM AB953 ab
INNER JOIN DailyFieldRecord dfr
    ON dfr.DailyFieldRecordID = ab.DailyFieldRecordID
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT AB1.DailyFieldRecordID,SUM(CASE WHEN AB1.ItemID IN (1302,1303,1305,1306) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EX
            FROM AB953 AB1
            GROUP BY AB1.DailyFieldRecordID) T
    ON dfr.DailyFieldRecordID = T.DailyFieldRecordID
WHERE dfr.ActivityCodeID = 387
    AND ab.GroupID = 260
```